# How to set DLL to native (Wine)

Tags: 13.10, wine, software-installation

I'm currently trying to setup MathCad14 on 13.10 using Wine 1.7.

Here are the [instructions](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10538) I'm using.

In there I'm told to:

> set all DLLs to Native (especially msvcm80.dll).

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open *Wine Configure* or `winecfg` from command-line.
2. Select Libraries tab: Enter name of DLL or select it from dropbox

   [image]
3. Click Add, it should be (native first then built-in) → Apply

   [image]

**Notes**:

- You may create new profile for MathCad from *Applications tab* if you don't want global settings.
- DLL override modes: It's possible to force only `native` or `builtin` DLL. But I recommend using these to cover both cases:
  `builtin, native` wine will try its builtin DLL then Microsoft native DLL
  `native, builtin` wine will try Microsoft native DLL then its own builtin DLL

  See [Chapter 4. Configuring Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#DLL_Overrides)
- Sometimes, it is needed to figure out which libs are loaded, this may help `WINEDEBUG=+loaddll wine yourprogram.exe`.

  See [General help on running applications under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/help/?sTopic=generic)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a big difference between native only and native, builtin?

Comment: I updated my answer