# Runtime Error ´380´ Invalid Property Value on Wine

Tags: wine

Im trying to run the .exe file (a software for hospital) but it shows Runtime Error ´380' Invalid Property Value. And the one thing that also happens when im going to execute it, the resolution of the desktop changes and doesnt go back to normal if you will not restart it.

I tried to install the dll files available on winetricks like what I read on the other forums and these are msls31, msmask, riched20, riched30, richtx32.

There is no output also about the error when the wine gives this error.

Is there any solution to this? Our company is planning to install ubuntu on computers but this program is needed by some employees.

Comment: What is this software ? Is it listed on https://www.winehq.org/, also WINE can be very hit or miss, do you know for a fact this software in wine ?

Comment: Sorry Sir for the late reply, its just a software created for our hospital

Comment: its a PIDSR a software created in the Philippines. Heres the link of the software that Im stated here http://pidsr.software.informer.com/4.0/

Comment: is there any other software or any emulator that can run this .exe on ubuntu

Comment: You could try the `play on linux` front end, it can auto config some software sometimes. There is also the `crossover` program, it is paid, though it has a free trail and commercial support. This software seems very niche and the thing about `wine` is it is developed for the popular software that most users want (games, office, stuff like that) even then it is very hit or miss, I highly recommend, based on the fact there is zero documentation of anyone ever running this on `wine`, that you do not rely on `wine` for a hospital.

Comment: Even if you get the program to run, there a features that won't work down the line. Think of `wine` like a games console emulator, nice to have, can work well in very specific circumstance but it is not 100% ever. `Runtime Error ´380´` is a very vague error and means simply, something is missing somewhere. I looked up this software, it is large and complex, `wine` is not for you

Comment: In-spite of that, your fix may be simple, are you running wine in xp mode ? Use wine tricks to try 7 or 8 instead.

Comment: Thanks sir for the reply, uhmm I tried crossover yesterday, the same problem happened also

Comment: I also tried play on linux but I think there is no option that you can open exe file there, there are only list of programs there that available on windows that you can install and download

Comment: I tried what you said to use wine tricks in windows 7 or 8 mode, but the same thing happen sir

Comment: sir there are some people from the other forum saying that I need to install oelaut32 dll but it doesnt show on winetricks

Comment: this software is very important for our company, the hr department uses this on windows. but the problem on windows are viruses and I think there is no enough fund to buy for high quality antiviruses so we decided to use linux but some software wont work on ubuntu

Comment: Sir do you think that there is any solution to this. where do you think is the error coming, On the software of .exe file that we need to use or on the wine or other emulators?

Comment: Sorry sir for the disturbance, we just needed this for our company badly

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it will work, I will try to help you though but we will need to go one step at a time, so to begin, here is oelaut32.dll (32bit download.dll-files.com/2c1467a6ff34e6e13920d9e546d47e50/oleaut32.zip?0XGhRHbKjQ ) (64bit download.dll-files.com/28480e2cf5d1e3015e037ba59d9dfef9/oleaut32.zip?0XGhRHcMkQ) Put this in the correct folder and try again, then let me know how it goes

Comment: sir where Im going to copy the downloaded dll

Comment: do i need to paste it on fakedlls folder??

Comment: sorry sir i dont know where path I will copy this dll

Comment: Put it in /home/username/.wine/ then in folder `wine` C:\windows\system

Comment: sir it shows that no such file or directory on terminal

Comment: sorry sir im a newbie on ubuntu

Comment: It would be `~/.wine/C:/windows/system` in terminal

Comment: sorry sir, the same thing happens also, I also tried to Enter location and paste your /home/username/.wine/ but it cant find the directory

Comment: sorry sir, i already find it know, sorry for being late thinker, i change the username, i didnt notice

Comment: sir I already pasted it on the path that are you saying

Comment: runtime error happens again, and when im going to install a dll again on winetricks, it doesnt show up yet on the list that i can download

Comment: Try adding it as native in wine tricks, then uninstall and reinstall PIDSR http://askubuntu.com/questions/431790/how-to-set-dll-to-native-wine

Comment: I already copied it on the folders of dll that can be seen in winetricks, it still doesnt show up

Comment: sir finished trying what you said on adding native in winetricks but it still doesnt show up

Comment: I also restarted the pc but it still doesnt show up also

Comment: i also try to remove the builtin and make native only